# The relief of a button isn't having any effect on its appearance in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I've been working on an autoclicker utilizing tkinter for the gui. I noticed that there isn't any clear way to tell if the autoclicker is toggled or not, so I tried adding a relief to the toggle button. However, the relief isn't affecting the button's appearance at all - it looks the same without relief and with a relief.

Initially the button's *relief* attribute is set to `raised`. In the `start_autoclicker` function (which runs the actual autoclicker), the line `self.start_stop_button.configure(relief='sunken')` runs before the autoclicker starts. In the `toggle_autoclicker` function, located below `self.running = False` is `self.start_stop_button.configure(relief='raised')`.

Clicking the button works properly, but the relief does not change the appearance.
I'm on macOS, here are two screenshots for comparison:

raised
[raised button, looks like default relief](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipAZS.png)

sunken
[sunked button, looks like default relief](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T200r.png)

Some code for reference:

The toggle button:

```py
self.start_stop_button = tk.Button(self, text="Toggle", command=self.toggle_autoclicker, relief="raised")
self.start_stop_button.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="w", padx=(0, 0), pady=(0, 30))
```

toggle_autoclicker:

```py
    def toggle_autoclicker(self):
        if not self.running:
            try:
                delay = float(self.click_delay_var.get())
                if delay < 0:
                    raise ValueError
                self.running = True
                self.start_autoclicker()
            except ValueError:
                messagebox.showerror("Invalid Interval", "Please enter a click interval greater than zero.")
        else:
            self.running = False
            self.start_stop_button.configure(relief='raised')
            print("+") # for debug
```

start_autoclicker:

```py
    def start_autoclicker(self):

        if self.key_var.get() == "" and self.mb == "KEY":
            self.running = False
            messagebox.showerror("Invalid Key","Please enter an alphanumeric character or symbol found on your device's keyboard.")
            return
        else:
            self.start_stop_button.configure(relief='sunken')
            print("-") # for debug

        def autoclick():
            while self.running:
                delay = float(self.click_delay_var.get())
                if self.mb == "LMB":
                    self.mouse_controller.click(Button.left, 1)
                elif self.mb == "RMB":
                    self.mouse_controller.click(Button.right, 1)
                elif self.mb == "KEY":
                    self.keyboard_controller.press(self.key_var.get())
                    self.keyboard_controller.release(self.key_var.get())
                time.sleep(delay)

        self.autoclicker_thread = threading.Thread(target=autoclick)
        self.autoclicker_thread.start()
```

I've done a bit of troubleshooting, but ultimately could not find much information. Please let me know if this post isn't clear enough or lacks needed info, and thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Consider accepting my answer if it helped, thank you!

Comment: Use `Checkbutton` with `indicatoron=0` to simulate a toggle button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change from the standard to the ttk button you can achieve this behavior with:

`self.start_stop_button.state(['pressed'])` to "press" or `self.start_stop_button.state(['!pressed'])` to "release".

To check the state use `self.start_stop_button.instate(['pressed'])`

But note, that the button can not be clicked if you set the state to pressed! Therefore i recommend rather changing the button text from "Start" to "Stop" instead so the button remains usable:

Instead of changing the relief `self.start_stop_button.configure(relief='sunken')` you can change the Button text and if you want also the color `self.start_stop_button.configure(text='Start', bg='green')`

Comment: It isn't a ttk button, is there anything else I should try?

Comment: I know, but changing your code to represent one is as easy as adding the import statement `from tkinter import ttk` and then changing `self.start_stop_button = tk.Button(self, text="Toggle", command=self.toggle_autoclicker)` to `self.start_stop_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Toggle", command=self.toggle_autoclicker`

Comment: But as I said setting the button to remain pressed means you can not press ist again which makes it useless for a toggle button. So consider to change the button text instead. I edited my answer to elaborate a bit more.